# Does Apple provide a function for converting CGSize to CGPoint?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgpoint

And the reverse.  It would not be difficult to write my own.  But I'd rather use Apple's if there is one.

Comment: But why would you ever need to do that? It makes very little sense: CGSize is a size, with absolute values in each coordinate, and CGPoint is a location relative to an origin, with directional values. Frequent conversion between them hints that you may be thinking about something wrong. (Hence Apple not having a function for it.)

Comment: I have functions for treating CGPoints as vectors and creating linear combinations.  Sometimes the size of something figures into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing that does this, they are inherently different mathematical ideas.

A size is an absolute measure of some quantifiable quality of an object, a point is an exact location in a coordinate space relative to a particular frame of reference.

Comment: I want to plot sizes on a graph. Should i not do this?

Comment: You may be able to have a one-to-one correlation between your data and your axes, but this would be a nice coincidence in your case.  You can do this, sure, just recognize the difference between data and its representation; you can't do this for all sets of data.